# Token question for organization use: Using Github Action to Push a folder to another Repo

Tags: github-actions, access-token

I have two repos, `repoA` and `repoB` in my GitHub organization, both shared by several members.

I want to push the auto-compiled (by GitHub Action) results of `repoA` to `repoB`.

Most of the GitHub action for pushing files to another repo requires a `token`, for instance, the one below:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-directory-to-another-repository

However, if I understand correctly, this token is generated from one person's computer (SSH) and added to the release repo.

Does this mean that all the members that push code to `repoA` will use the same token (from member X, let say) in the GitHub Action to push results into `repoB`?

If this is not the case, how should this be set up so that everyone (member X, Y, Z) who pushes to `repoA` will have access to the correct "records" for `repoB`?

It seems the [server-to-server-token](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#server-to-server-tokens) should be the right choice.

More explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: For what I understand reading the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#about-the-github_token-secret) it seems the generates github token doesn't depend on the user who made a push. Now, if you want to be sure to use the same token for each user from the organization, I suggest creating a service account, as member of the org, and create a PAT for this user, using it in the org wokfkows

Comment: I'm exploring this same problem, not yet, but this github app has looked the most promising to me so far: https://github.com/qoomon/github-actions-access-manager